# How to remove from Mobile App via private app in shopify api

Tags: php, shopify

I tried removing it with:

```
PUT /admin/products/#{product_id}.json
{
"product": {
"id": 632910392,
"published": false
  }
}
```

But only unpublished from Online Store and not Mobile App, any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The RestAPI has no attribute for that. There is the Sales Channels API you might check into, Product Listings which might help, and finally, explore the GraphQL calls to do with Products. Shopify may expose what you're looking for through a mutation on the product via GraphQL.